# Need to install ethernet firmware for Dell PowerEdge 2650 integrated BCM5703 NIC

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, ethernet, firmware

I have a Dell Poweredge 2650 and I'm trying to install the ethernet firmware/driver. I found this [page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/bge.4freebsd.html) but I can't figure out how to install it. Their isn't a loader.conf and I would like to avoid modding the kernel. I am using 12.04 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `bge` driver and `loader.conf` is actually for FreeBSD. With Linux and the Broadcom 5703 chipset I think you'll need the `tg3` driver, or possibly `bnx2` but most likely `tg3`. Try doing:

```
sudo modprobe tg3
ifconfig -a
```

`modprobe` should give no output and `ifconfig` should show the NIC. You should be able to use the NIC just fine once the driver is correctly loaded. If you do want to update the firmware anyway, you'll need to have the driver loaded first. You may be able to do any firmware updates following [the Ubuntu instructions](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/firmware), but if there is difficulty you may need to boot to the [Dell OpenManage Live CD](http://linux.dell.com/files/openmanage-contributions/omsa-64-live/OMSA64-CentOS55-x86_64-LiveCD.iso) and do the updates from that environment.

Let us know how it goes!